# Как запустить установочный файл qt в Ubuntu22.04?

Tags: qt, ubuntu

Всем привет. Пытаюсь установить Qt в Ubuntu22.04, но когда пытаюсь открыть 'qt-unified-linux-x64-4.5.2-online.run' файл ничего не происходит. Через терминал тоже самое. Как я могу это исправить?

Comment: А зачем? Чем вас не устроила версия Qt из официальных репозиториев Ubuntu?

Comment: Попробуйте через терминал `chmod +x имяфайла.run`, потом `./имяфайла.run`

Comment: через терминал тоже не получается, я уже пытался вводить такую команду

Comment: при установке ubuntu я скачал такой образ: ubuntu-22.04.2-desktop-amd64.iso. Я так понимаю это для архитектуры x64 amd, а у меня x64 intel. Это может играть роль?

Comment: amd64, x86_64 и x64 — это всё одно и то же, производитель не имеет значения

Comment: Что означает «не получается»? Что происходит вместо того, что вы ожидаете? (И почему вас всё ещё не устраивает Qt из официальных репозиториев?)

Comment: Ничего не происходит. Будто то я ничего не нажимал. Я обычно устанавливаю через онлайн установщик, при установке выбираю то что мне надо. Через репозиторий ни разу не устанавливал

Comment: Файл-то вообще непустой хотя бы?

Comment: нет. весит 57Мб. Такая проблема у меня только на ubuntu, на винде все хорошо устанавливается

Comment: Слово «online» навевает вопрос — а может, вы находитесь в стране, против которой Qt объявил санкции, и из-за этого весь онлайн теперь не работает, например?

Comment: У меня подключен vpn, иначе я не смог бы скачать установщик. К тому же на винде установщик нормально работает